How to map rest resource, domain model and entity
I have a shop object where one area can only contain only one open shop.
Entity model
@Entity
Public class Shop{
 @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
 String Name;
 String Area;
 String closed;

} 

Domain Model
Public class ShopModel{
 
 String Name;
 String Area; //unique identifier of shop
 String closed;

} 

Rest resource
Public class ShopResource{
 String id;
 String Name;
 String Area;
 String closed;

} 

The conversions when we get any request as per my understanding will take place as below:
Resource -> Domain model -> Entity and back  Entity -> Domain model -> Resource
I have to create CRUD Rest api and I have to expose get each shop resource based on id. In that case,
I am confused on how we can map id in resource object if my domain model is missing id attribute?
Is this right approach? Should we directly convert entity to resource instead and keep domain only to perform business logic? Or add id attribute to my Domain model.
Kindly suggest what is the right way.

Step 1. Define a shop resource:
/shops/{id}

Step 2. Define method for the HTTP GET method on API layer (pseudocode):
ShopResource get(Long id) {
   return new ShopResource(shops.shop(id));
}

Step 3. Define the class on the domain layer:
class Shops {
   Shop shop(Long id) {
      // invoke data layer
   }
}

You can have the id in the Shop or set it in the API layer since you know it from request (depends on other uses of the object, in this case it is not important).
P.S. I recommend you think about how you will ensure data integrity in the database, you will probably need more than one table. For example, think about a scenario where you have 3 stores in one area: 1 open, 2 closed, how your database will not allow the status of one store to change so that it becomes 2 open and 1 closed.
